# jQuery Pagination with Sets of Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I am implementing pagination to my web application and would like to display only 5 pages at a time (pages 1-5, pages 6-10, etc.)

Say my total number of pages returned is 100; Using a for loop, can I update my set of 5 pages from 1-5 to 6-10 until the total number of pages is reached? So something like this:

```
 numOfElemnets = 5 //pages to be displayed at once
 totalPages = 100;
 for(var i=0; i<totalPages; i++) {
     $("#toolbar .pagination li a").attr('href', 'page=" + i + "'); //div containing <a> elements
 }
```

[image]

Or if I have this concept completely wrong and there's a better way to implement, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this:

```
 numOfElemnets = 5 //pages to be displayed at once
 totalPages = 100; //total pages
 currentPage = 3; //this is shouldn't be static, since it's the current page the user is at

 /**
 * If the user is on page 1 to 5, the first page will be 1. If he's not, then the page will be the current page minus 5.
 * This is to stop it from starting the loop from a negative number, since you don't have a -4 page.
 */
 if(currentPage > numOfElemnets) {
    i = currentPage - numOfElemnets;
 } else {
    i = 1;
 }

 // The same thing as above for the end. You will take 5 pages after the current page, but if you're on page 99, you should pick just till 100 that is your limit.
 if(currentPage + numOfElemnets > totalPages) {
    end = totalPages;
 } else {
    end = currentPage + numOfElemnets;
 }

  // I changed the for to a while, since the i parameter had to get out of the for. You can still use a for and give the i as a parameter. Whatever.
 while(i <= end) {
    $("#toolbar .pagination li a").attr('href', 'page=" + i + "'); //div containing <a> elements
    i++;
 }
```